# Disable/remove button permanently after click

Tags: php, button

I understand how easy it is to hide/remove/disable a button after clicking client-sided. However, I would like to hide/disable a button permanently after it's been clicked once.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="delivery-confirm-frm">
    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $_order->getIncrementId(); ?>" />
    <input type="button" value="CONFIRM" class="delivery-confirm" id="confirmbutton"/>
</form>




<script type="text/javascript">
var $jj = jQuery.noConflict();
$jj(document).ready(function () {
    $jj('.delivery-confirm').on('click', function () {
        var _this = $jj(this);
        $jj.confirm({
            title: 'Confirm!',
            content: 'Are you sure? Once confirmed, you cannot dispute this transaction.',
            buttons: {
                confirm: function () {
                    _this.closest('form').submit();
                },
                cancel: function () {

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Basically, I have a button a person will click to confirm that an order has been delivered to them. An alert confirmation pops up after clicking.  I would like to remove the button after the person has confirmed via the alert pop up.

Is there a simple way to do this via PHP? Or is it a little more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to implement both client side and server side. Client side is for once the user clicks on submit for the first time so using javascript you can call the following after the form submit:

```
$("#confirmbutton").prop("disabled",true);
```

after that you need to handle the case that a user reloads the page. So the button should be disabled when the page loads. So assuming that there is a function `is_confirmed()` that returns true or false, you can add the following in your button

```
<input type="button" value="CONFIRM" class="delivery-confirm" id="confirmbutton" <?php echo $_order->is_confirmed() ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>/>
```